# Facebook Login Error Invalid Scope: users_friends

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I have created an App using the Facebook Login and when I run the App I get this below error.

> error: canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if(FBSDKAccessToken.current()==nil){
        print("Not Logged In")
    }
    else{
        print("Logged In..")
    }

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.delegate = self
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","users_friends"]
    loginButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    if(error == nil){
        print("login complete")

    }
    else{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("Logged out..")
}
}
```

[What I've got on Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCHM6.png)

[The error I get on the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75qBt.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `user_friends` not `users_friends`. [Permissions Reference - Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)

Answer (score 1):

Add this line into your info.plist file.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    </array>
```